# python regex optional non capturing space

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I want to match:

!argument1 [argument2], where argument2 is optional. I have it figured out using a second optional group, but I can't get it to ignore the space between the arguments.

regex="!([a-z]*) ?\W(.*)"

Matches:
"!test case"

"!test "

Not matching:
"!test"

I tried to throw in an '?(: )' in the regex to make a non capturing optional group containing the space but to no avail, resulting in the following: regex="!([a-z]*)?(: )?\W(.*)"

The result is 'raise error, v # invalid expression'

some tries usin the python shell:

```
>>>  regex="!([a-z]*) ?\W(.*)"
>>> data="!hello dear"
>>> re.search(regex, data).groups()
('hello', 'dear')
>>> data="!hello "
>>> re.search(regex, data).groups()
('hello', '')
>>> data="!hello"
>>> re.search(regex, data).groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Comment: It should be `!([a-z]+)`

Comment: You've only made the space optional. The second group is mandatory.

Comment: could you post the actual input and expected output?

Comment: user3218114: my wildcard is missing due to formatting. user2357112: Well yes, but I dont mind if its empty. Is it better if I add the (optional) whitespace to the secondary group and when I want to make use of that data I simply strip the whitespace?

Comment: Why u need a space before \W  \W (means non word char)
so you can simply use !([a-z]+)\W?(.*)
optional non word char followed by second group which is captured then

Comment: !([a-z]+) ?(.*)  will work as well if you want to have space only and not all NON-Word characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex in the comments should fullfill your requirements `!([a-z]+) ?(.*)` 
You require a ! followed by a sequence of characters (your first argument) then there might be a space and another capturing group which could be empty(so missing) or contain any characters after the space

Answer (score 0):

Overcomplicated.

```
import re
e = re.compile("(!?\w+)")
s = "!test ing code"
args = e.findall(s)[0][0]
print args
```

> ['!test', 'ing', 'code']

then just check if `args[0][0] == "!"`

I assume this is for a bot of some sort, probably an IRC one, could look at phenny.

Even easier would be to see if your commands starts with `!` and strip it before branching to the regex parser. Then you can just capture `\w+`